# Display Custom Marker in Google Maps Using Relative File Path

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using Google's Javascript APi v.3.0 to develop a web app. I want to be able to display custom markers, but they don't show up when I try to add them. I've written a helper function in Javascript to display a custom marker:

```
function addCustomMarker(iconFile,iconTitle,lat,lng){
   var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:loc,
      icon:iconFile,
      title: iconTitle,
      zIndex:2
   });
   marker.setMap(map);//Where map is a google.maps.Map already defined
}
```

I'm currently testing locally and my file structure sort of looks like:

- /Maps Application

  - map.htm
  - /Images

    - markerImage.png

Elsewhere in the html file, I then call the javascript function like:

```
addCustomMarker('Images/markerImage.png', 'Custom Marker', 20, 50);
```

However, this does not work. No marker is displayed. If I comment out the "icon: markerIcon," line, then the default marker is displayed, which tells me that it can't find the image file.

Is there a way to reference marker images from a relative path like I am trying to do? I've tried './Images/markerImage.png' and '/Images/markerImage.png' as well, and neither work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I also think relative paths work. I tried it locally and it works fine. I believe `icon:` just places the value into a `src` of an `img` tag, or something of the sort.

Here's my example:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, 
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0), 
  icon: "icons/ride_red.png"});
```

`icons` is a folder in the same folder where the JavaScript/HTML file is.

Are you sure you have the capitalization correct? What if you tried "hardcoding" the `icon` option, that is:

```
icon: 'Images/markerImage.png',
```

Now here's a silly question: have you also tried opening that `markerImage.png` in your browser?

Beside local pages, [here's a page](https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/geocodesp_small.html) that has relative icon paths. You check the "Metro SP Stations" checkbox to display the icons. If you look at the source,

```
     estacao = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: toLatLng(estacao_data.posn[0], estacao_data.posn[1]),
        icon: 'metrosp/' + estacao_data.icon[0] + '.png',
        title: estacao_data.name,
        visible: false
      });
```

Then you can navigate to the `metrosp` folder and see the images are all there:

https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/metrosp/

Comment: So after a bit more digging into my problem, it turns out I had two issues. 1 was that I did in fact have a capitalization error in my code and 2, I'm actually testing this using a QWebVeiw (QT/C++ program) as the browser and there appear to be issues with QWebView not displaying the custom image. I didn't mention that I was using QWebView because I assumed it was irrelevant and that it would display anything like Chrome or Firefox would. So now the html/Javascript displays fine in Chrome, I just need to figure out what's wrong with QWebView.

Comment: Wish I could help you with the QWebView. Glad to hear about your progress!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use a relative address for the image. The pin is displayed on a page from a different server, so you have to use the complete address.

Comment: In a small prototype I wrote recently, the markers have all custom images with relative paths and it works well. All elements inside the map are local to your server -- unless you are using default elements. The whole map is inside a div on your page.